# How can I iterate over the posts of a section using Zola?

Tags: rust, template-engine, zola, tera

I tried the following, which I found in the Zola documentation but it didn't render anything. The Tera docs weren't rewarding either.

```
{% for post in section.pages %}
  <h1><a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to iterate over a paginated section is as following:

```
{% for post in paginator.pages %}
  <h1><a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}
```

`paginator` is described in the Templates section under Pagination: [getzola.org/documentation/templates](https://www.getzola.org/documentation/templates/pagination/).

A paginated section gets the same section variable as a normal section page minus its pages. The pages are instead in `paginator.pages`.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what is the difference? Is `paginator` a special term in Zola or is it a variable in your code?

Comment: @PeterHall I'm unsure, I've been delving into Zola/Tera and this is what I came up with after checking out how a working theme managed to do it: https://github.com/shalzz/butler/blob/master/templates/blog.html
I think it has to do with the fact it's a 'paginated' section but I can't find 'paginator' in any of the docs...

Comment: `paginator` is described in the Templates section under Pagination: https://www.getzola.org/documentation/templates/pagination/